# Git maven release windows commandline

Tags: java, git, maven

i try to use the maven-release-plugin for my first time... at the moment i have problems to do the git push.

If i just do a simple "git push" in my project, all works fine. But the push which the maven-release-plugin does fails... may be my scm settings are wrong. I have found many other posts about this, tried different things but i was not able to get it work. So i'am sry that this is one more git maven release plugin post...

Here my parts of my pom.xml:

```
...
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.2</version>
</plugin>
...
<scm>
  <connection>scm:git:ssh://marcus@gregor.be/repo/git/lara/MyParent</connection>
  <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://marcus@gregor.be/repo/git/lara/MyParent/</developerConnection>
  <tag>MyParent-0.0.1</tag>
</scm>
...
```

Trace output of the commandline (Windows7), simple push:

```
C:\Users\mypc\git\lara\MyParent>git push
warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value has changed in
Git 2.0 from 'matching' to 'simple'. To squelch this message
and maintain the traditional behavior, use:

  git config --global push.default matching

To squelch this message and adopt the new behavior now, use:

  git config --global push.default simple

When push.default is set to 'matching', git will push local branches
to the remote branches that already exist with the same name.

Since Git 2.0, Git defaults to the more conservative 'simple'
behavior, which only pushes the current branch to the corresponding
remote branch that 'git pull' uses to update the current branch.

See 'git help config' and search for 'push.default' for further information.
(the 'simple' mode was introduced in Git 1.7.11. Use the similar mode
'current' instead of 'simple' if you sometimes use older versions of Git)

Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '178.191.160.162' to
the list of known hosts.
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/mypc/.ssh/id_rsa':
Counting objects: 4, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 380 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://marcus@gregor.be/repo/git/lara/
   6c59435..dc336e9  master -> master

C:\Users\mypc\git\lara\MyParent>
```

Here the maven-release plugin output:

```
C:\Users\mypc\git\lara\MyParent>mvn release:prepare
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building MyParent 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:2.5.2:prepare (default-cli) @ MyParent ---

[INFO] Verifying that there are no local modifications...
[INFO]   ignoring changes on: **\pom.xml.next, **\release.properties, **\pom.xml
.branch, **\pom.xml.tag, **\pom.xml.backup, **\pom.xml.releaseBackup
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git rev-parse --show-toplevel"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\Users\mypc\git\lara\MyParent
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git status --porcelain ."
[INFO] Working directory: C:\Users\mypc\git\lara\MyParent
[WARNING] Ignoring unrecognized line: ?? MyParent/release.properties
[INFO] Checking dependencies and plugins for snapshots ...
What is the release version for "MyParent"? (com.mystuff:MyParent)
0.0.1: :
What is SCM release tag or label for "MyParent"? (com.mystuff:MyParentPar
ent) MyParent-0.0.1: :
What is the new development version for "MyParent"? (com.mystuff:MyParent
Parent) 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT: :
[INFO] Transforming 'MyParent'...
[INFO] Not generating release POMs
[INFO] Executing goals 'clean verify'...
[WARNING] Maven will be executed in interactive mode, but no input stream has be
en configured for this MavenInvoker instance.
[INFO] [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] [INFO]

[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------
------
[INFO] [INFO] Building MyParent 0.0.1
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------
------
[INFO] [INFO]
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ MyParent
---
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------
------
[INFO] [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------
------
[INFO] [INFO] Total time: 0.297 s
[INFO] [INFO] Finished at: 2016-02-02T16:03:27+01:00
[INFO] [INFO] Final Memory: 7M/147M
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------
------
[INFO] Checking in modified POMs...
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git add -- pom.xml"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\Users\mypc\git\lara\MyParent
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git rev-parse --show-toplevel"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\Users\mypc\git\lara\MyParent
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git status --porcelain ."
[INFO] Working directory: C:\Users\mypc\git\lara\MyParent
[WARNING] Ignoring unrecognized line: ?? MyParent/pom.xml.releaseBackup
[WARNING] Ignoring unrecognized line: ?? MyParent/release.properties
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git commit --verbose -F C:\Users\MYPC\AppDa
ta\Local\Temp\maven-scm-1583955201.commit pom.xml"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\Users\mypc\git\lara\MyParent
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git symbolic-ref HEAD"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\Users\mypc\git\lara\MyParent
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git push ssh:********@gregor.be/repo/git/lara/
MyParent refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\Users\mypc\git\lara\MyParent
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.866 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-02-02T16:03:28+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/147M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5
.2:prepare (default-cli) on project MyParent: Unable to commit files
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-push command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] Permission denied (publickey).
[ERROR] fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please make sure you have the correct access rights
[ERROR] and the repository exists.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureExc
eption

C:\Users\mypc\git\lara\MyParent>
```

So the public keys should be available, because the simple push call also works... so i believe the scm is wrong... but i don't know what is wrong... hope anybody can help me. Thanks a lot in advance. KR

Update:
I've tried to enter the push command which maven uses in the command line, it worked ( i just replaced the * with the right data):
cmd.exe /X /C "git push ssh://marcus@gregor.be/repo/git/lara refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master"

So why does it works when i enter it into the cmd and not when maven calls the command?!

Comment: Are you using a credentials manager for git on windows? Also you should execute this on the command line to squelch spam: `git config --global push.default simple`

Comment: No, i don't use a credentials manager (or at least i don't know). I've entered your git config command, but no change...